# Postgresql Procedure select into temp table

Tags: sql, postgresql, nested

Being a recent convert from SQL Server, I am getting to know Postgresql a bit.

I really hate having to write nested selevt statements in SQL since I find that the readability and maintainability of the code suffers when I do.

Usually I would create a stored procedure in SQL Server where I would select something into a temporary table, that I can then use in another select statement.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE Procname
AS

BEGIN

SELECT
    Somewhere.Col_1,
    Somewhere.Col_2

INTO
    #Temptable

FROM
    Somewhere Somewhere

SELECT
    Temptable.Col_1,
    Somewhere_Else.Col3

FROM
    #Temptable Temptable

INNER JOIN
    Somewhere_Else.Col_2 = Temptable.Col_2

END
```

When I execute this procedure I would get returned the final select query

How would I replicate this procedure in Postgresql?

I know that you can select into a temporary table, but I cannot seem to figure out how to use this table in the next select statement within the same procedure

Comment: (1) I'm lost, you are not even using the temporary table in your stored procedure.  (2) You shouldn't use a stored procedure to return a table; use a view or table-valued function.  (3) Both databases support CTEs which is likely what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry I wrote that example code a bit to fast. Generally I am looking into a project where I would have to use calculated columns within new calculated columns etc. etc. Using nested select statements this gets old really fast, which is why I love using procedures and selecting into temp tables that I can then join whenever needed

Comment: Using temporary tables in this manner is an antipattern sadly common among the SQL Server users. Don't apply it to other DBMSes.

Comment: What then would be a good way to avoid nested select statements (I'd like to use joins rather than nested statements as much as possible)

Comment: Ahh I see a solution utilizing CTE's.

Seems to fit the requirement at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Create a set returning function, there is no need for a temp table at all.

```
CREATE function Procname()
  returns table(col_1 ???, col2 ???) --<< change data types here
AS
$$
  SELECT
      Temptable.Col_1,
      Somewhere_Else.Col3
  FROM Somewhere Temptable
    INNER JOIN Somewhere_Else ON Somewhere_Else.Col_2 = Temptable.Col_2;
$$
language sql
stable;
```

But for such a simple statement, I would rather create a view.